# how to find accurate the "Total Testing duration time" in Jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I would like to know if there is a JMeter listener that displays the total time that a test has been running for.

Although [this](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) plugin shows elapsed time/total duration time along the x-axis, it gives this value in seconds but I would like the value in milliseconds.

Please tell me how can i get the total duration/elapsed time of testing in millisecond?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to use this data? At the risk of stating the obvious, could you not just multiply seconds by 1000?

Comment: No,Actually the value lie between 1 and 2 second

Comment: Instead of this this JMeter Graph plugin is there any other listener which can give the duration time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer to the question (which has been clarified based on comments) is no, AFAIK there is no listener that displays, to the screen, the total time that the test has been running for in milliseconds.

If you want this value, however, you would simply have to subtract the first timestamp from the last timestamp in the results file. This would give - more or less - the total number of milliseconds that the test ran for. I say more or less because the start and end points are subjective, some people might say the start point is the first request, others would say it is when JMeter is initiated - these can be different times.

If you really must have the value inside of the GUI then you could use the setup and teardown thread groups and a simple beanshell calculation to work out the time. Again, this is subject to interpretation as the setup TG will fire *before* the test has started. Not much before but a few milliseconds to be sure.

Comment: It is actually elapsed Time means the time before sending request to the time after receiving the response till the last byte.I have done alot researh on it.

Comment: So, 'elapsed time' in the scope of JMeter is what is shown in this graph, in milliseconds. Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: ok thanks for your this graph now my question becomes easy can you tell me If your last point was 9th point which is between 8 and 9 second so can u able to tell me what exactly is the Elapsed Time(on X-Axis)in millisecond? If yes then how ?

Comment: I suspect you have Response Time / Elapsed Time confusion. The x-axis (horizontal) is how long the test was running for. The y-axis (vertical) shows how long each request took. If not, then I have to confess to having no idea what your question is!

Comment: Yes my friend you didn't get my question. I am saying can you tell me how long the test was run in millisecond.I think now it will be understandable for you :)

Comment: Edited question and answer to reflect comments

Answer (score 2):

Note that starting from next version of Apache JMeter (> 2.7), there will be a new listener called Response Time Graph listener that will give you what you need.

This version is available now as nightly build:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html