# JMeter throughput value in grafana

Tags: jmeter, influxdb, grafana

I refer to the "http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana/" article,

through grafana + infludx but there is a jmeter tps (throughput) value I do not know how get?

I tried "jmeter.all.h.count" but it did not seem to be the value I wanted:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the blog you were referring to!

We can not expect the backend listener metrics to give you an accurate result as you expect in the aggregate report - (specially percentiles, avg etc)

BackEndListener basically gives the metrics over time. You should plot the graph using the data over time. If you try to use single stat metric of Grafana with that data , then you will see a complete mismatch.

---

In the blog - I was using the modified apache_core.jar library to get the results as you are actually expecting. However I stopped sharing (after jmeter 2.13, jmeter 3.0) the modified lib.

Comment: Very glad to see your reply! I think I know what you mean, finally, want to ask in your blog reviews see such a "If you need throughput which is number of requests processed per unit time you can query -" jmeter.all.a.count "- group by 1 sec, 1 min as you want.
Select sum (value) from jmeter.all.a.count"
Group by field - enter 1s or 60s "that would be able to get throughput, I want to try, there seems to be something similar, this is my last attempt:)

Comment: @blue, what version of JMeter are you using?

Comment: jmeter version is 3.3

Comment: @blue I have included the modified jar for JMeter version 3.3 - You can download if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I still think about what modules you've changed so that I can learn and improve

Comment: @blue , I modified org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser

Comment: @vins Do you have a version of the jar for Jmeter 4.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to wrong component for values.

For GraphiteBackendListenerClient, sent values are described here:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html

For InfluxdbBackendListenerClient, sent values can be found here:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/components/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/influxdb/InfluxdbBackendListenerClient.java

Both components don't send throughput as it can be computed using Grafana and other metrics.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried "InfluxdbBackendListenerClient" but still did not find "throughput" value

Comment: Thank you. I also feel that need other solutions to get throughput  value:(

Comment: Wait 1 or 2 days, and if there's no better answer, I'll accept , because it doesn't solve my problem completely

Answer (score 0):

Found your answer in [influxdb grafana tutorial](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana/), 
Use `jmeter.all.a.count`:

> If I query the “jmeter.all.a.count” which has the no of requests processed for every second by the server, I get below output. [No of requests processed / unit time = Throughput]

Comment: Thank you@user7294900 there's also a question, and now I know Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time)
You can get TPS, I know number of requests= SELECT sum ("value") FROM "jmeterall.a.count" WHERE $timeFilter, but I don't know "total time" =? How do you get it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245475/how-to-find-accurate-the-total-testing-duration-time-in-jmeter

Comment: Thank you very much@@user7294900. I'll try it

Comment: Hello@user7294900, I try and try and know the "total time" meaning, but I still do not know exactly what should write in grafana, SELECT sum ("value") /unit time??? FROM "jmeterall.a.count" WHERE $timeFilter, here I don't know how to the "unit time" become " total time" ? wait for a reply, thank you

Comment: I am using Jmeter 4.0 and using https://grafana.com/dashboards/3351 for my dashboards. Using the following for TPS is no where close to what Jmeter reports say -  ```SELECT last("count") FROM "jmeter" WHERE "application" =~ /^$Application$/ AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($aggregation) fill(null)```